# Fetch images from public instagram user

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

How can i use instagram api without the need for user to login? Say my apps is a signage and user only need to put their instagram url and the images will be shown in a slideshow component. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it possible? That's something for you to discover. Stack Overflow only recommend code specific questions related to a problem or error. As for your answer, visit Instagram API, read their documentation and look at the end point to see what parameters does the API require and sort of return is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their documentation [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) you will need to authenticate users on behalf of your application if you want to access their media and other information. So to put this in other way it doesn't look possible to retrieve their media just by entering a URL without any authentication.